# Bash is not sourcing ~/.bash_profile on OSX

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, osx

I just got this really weird problem. When I start bash, I get these two lines:

```
-bash: fasd: kommandot finns inte
-bash: brew: kommandot finns inte
```

"kommandot finns inte" means command does not exist in Swedish (the more you know!). Also, my prompt is not colored and what not. Most of this seems to be resolved as soon as I type

```
source ~/.bash/profile
```

Another weird thing is that I suddenly can't get colors with

```
ls -G
```

although when I rename my `.bash_profile` this goes away (the `ls -G` thing).

None of this was a problem a very short time ago.

The last few days I have configured my dotfiles. The major things I did was to move many of them (`~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_prompt`, `~./aliases`, etc.) to a *dotfiles* folder and symlink them to the home folder. I also installed a bunch of stuff with homebrew. My dotfiles' github repo is [here](https://github.com/Poxnox/dotfiles).

I'm really confused right now, help is very appreciated!

Comment: Can you add a `ls -la` from your home? And a `file ~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: Do you meen that I should paste it here?

Comment: The files starting with dot are enough.

Comment: Just look in my github repo I linked to.

Comment: This doesn't help much. I need to see the symlinks in action. And normally, .bash_profile  sources .bashrc, not vv.

Answer (score 1):

You should have `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` at least and may have `.profile`, `.bash_aliases`, `.bash_logout` and many, many other files in your home directory that affect bash. The exact structure of such files changes with the OS and personalization by the user.

For a full answer you need to provide the full output of `ls ~/.bash*` and if `~/.profile` or `~/.environment` exist, at the very least.

It will help if you read: [Choosing](https://superuser.com/q/789448/353322), [Difference](https://superuser.com/q/183870/353322), [Start up](http://ss64.com/osx/syntax-bashrc.html), and specially [Order](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/10/execution-sequence-for-bash_profile-bashrc-bash_login-profile-and-bash_logout/). That will clarify the difference in which files are loaded for an interactive shell, a login shell and for scripts.

After that, you need to check that all relevant file links are in place.

And note that an existing `~/.bash_login` will prevent the loading of `~/.bash_profile`, for example.

Then, for your specific OS (OS X) [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4493499/2350426). It is not perfect, but it shows: how the user has inserted `if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi` in the `~/.bash_profile` file to ensure that `~/.bashrc` is loaded.

So: this is not a simple answer, but the shell startup setup is never simple.
Do look inside the files to find which file loads what.

Answer (score 1):

I am stupid... The problem was the exports. I forgot that I moved the definition of /usr/local/bin in PATH to ~/.exports from /etc/paths. All I had to do was source the ~/.exports first in ~/.bash_profile.

The ls color problem was from *GNU core utilities* that I installed via homebrew. Apparently it doesn't support the G flag, like os x's ls does.